# Why would a website not load?

Tags: web, network-programming

I went to a web page and it would not load. The browsers, Chrome and Firefox both said “Waiting…” and never gave an error or page can’t load, just continually said “Waiting…” In fact, in Chrome it was like that for over thirty minutes and never did load. I could load other websites with no problem; I thought there was something wrong with the website on the server.

Unfortunately I did not think to try it in IE at that time.

My Firefox browser’s cache I had been cleaning frequently, almost daily (localhost developing, nothing major). So when I posted the original question; a very bright, unselfish and polite Stackoverflow member suggested I clean my cache (remove the cookies, etc..) I did. And the page loaded. Same with Chrome. After all that, I did try it in IE and it loaded.

The web page was a simple one page with one image 950x648 pixels.
Why would that happen? I want to rule out the server side, but I had never experienced that before. (At least I don’t think so…) Could it be my internet connection, my router? My computer? Some settings? I'm leaning towards my computer, but where do I start to diagnosis this, if it is.

Is this the right section of the site to ask this question? Is there another site I should consider to ask this question?

#### UPDATE

Given the excellent resources listed below, I am ruling out the website and server. I will focus on the browsers and watch for this anomaly to repeat. Any thoughts, or course of action, would be greatly appreciated. Thx.

Comment: What's the URL of the web page?

Comment: http://eastsidepropertysolutions.com/

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps try this site:

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: +1 Yeah that's interesting site. I tried a couple of sites I knew were down, and it worked! Well, back to what I believe is a browser issue. :(

Comment: Who does your dns? Is this home or work? Might be with that (taking a slower outdated route or something). I'm a dev not a network guy so...

Comment: No one else has seem to of had the same problem, so I'm ruling out the website. I'm going to focus on my browsers and keep an eye on them. Well be using "Clive's" ping trick if I get future problems. What answers that will give, IDK.

Answer (score 1):

It loads perfectly for me, must be your browser/network setup. Try opening Terminal (or Command Prompt) and executing `ping eastsidepropertysolutions.com`. If you get a reply then the connection from your network to the website is fine, most likely indicating a browser issue.

Comment: That was neat trick. I will keep that in mind for the future. "browser/network setup" Hmmm, where do I start?